# Get version of Windows process using python

Tags: python, windows, process, python-2.5

Is there a way to get the "Product version" of a running Windows process as shown in the "Details" tab of its properties using Python?

Thanks a lot for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/):

```
>>> import win32api
>>> info = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(r'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe', '\\')
>>> '%s.%s.%s.%s' % (
...     info['FileVersionMS'] >> 16,
...     info['FileVersionMS'] & 0xffff,
...     info['FileVersionLS'] >> 16,
...     info['FileVersionLS'] & 0xffff)
'5.1.2600.5512'
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. But I need to have the "Product version" of a running process. Additionally, ver() seems not exactly return the same results as dsiplayed in the properties of the process

Comment: @Rickson1982, Can you show me each reuslt of  `platform.platform()` and `ver` and `priperties of the process` in your system?

Comment: ver returns "Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]", platform.platform() returns "Microsoft-Windows-32bit-WindowsPE". If I open a command window and open the corresponding process in the Windows Task Manager the field Properties/Details/Product version is "6.1.7601.17514""

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But this was not exactly what I needed. I could go around this problem somehow else.